# Vaadin does not navigate from specific page

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I have created a Vaadin app with a VehiclePage and its detailspage as well as a profile page and a View where i can see all registered Users and their detailsView respectively. The strange thing now is no matter on which page i am, i can navigate to every page from the Menubar, except when i am on the UserDetailsView. When i click any other page on the menubar the loading bar vom Vaadin starts and ends about 1 fifth before the end and the url does not change and nothing happens. I also do net get any errors. What is the problem here?

I opened the project on Github so you can try it yourself. When navigating to the users tab and then click on any user to get to the details you will not be able to navigato to any other page except from manually typing in the url: https://github.com/WoistdasNiveau/OegegEtdFullStack/tree/ValidationImplemented

EDIT: I  just checked with Fiddler and the vaadin app does not even send any Http Request to navigate away from this view.

The detailsView:

```
@PageTitle("User details | OegegEtd")
@Route(value = "user", layout = MainLayout.class)
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public class UserDetailsView extends VerticalLayout //implements HasUrlParameter<String>
{
    // == view fields ==
    H2 userTilte = new H2("User");
    H2 responsibleForTitle = new H2("Responsible for");
    TextField responsibleForField = new TextField();
    H2 createdVehiclesTitle = new H2("Created vehicles");
    TextField createdVehiclesField = new TextField();
    H2 updatedVehiclesTitle = new H2("Updated vehicles");
    TextField updatedVehiclesField = new TextField();
    H2 createdWorksTitle = new H2("Created works");
    TextField createdWorksField = new TextField();
    H2 updatedWorksTitle = new H2("Updated works");
    TextField updatedWorksField = new TextField();
    Grid<UserDisplay> userGrid = new Grid<>(UserDisplay.class,false);
    Button resendButton = new Button("Resend email");
    Grid<VehicleDisplay> createdVehiclesGrid = new Grid<>(VehicleDisplay.class, false);
    Grid<VehicleDisplay> updatedVehiclesGrid = new Grid<>(VehicleDisplay.class, false);
    Grid<WorkDisplay> responsibleForGrid = new Grid<>(WorkDisplay.class, false);
    Grid<WorkDisplay> createdWorksGrid = new Grid<>(WorkDisplay.class, false);
    Grid<WorkDisplay> updatedWorksGrid = new Grid<>(WorkDisplay.class, false);
    Button deleteButton = new Button("Delete User");

    UserForm userForm;

    // == private fields ==
    private final UserService _userService;
    private final VehicleService _vehicleService;
    private final WorkService _workService;
    private final EmailSenderService _emailSenderService;
    private String userIdentifier;
    private UserDisplay user;
    private boolean sameUser = false;
    private List<String> authorities;

    // == constructor ==
    public UserDetailsView(UserState userState, UserService _userService, VehicleService _vehicleService, WorkService _workService, EmailSenderService emailSenderService)
    {
        this._userService = _userService;
        this._vehicleService = _vehicleService;
        this._workService = _workService;
        this._emailSenderService = emailSenderService;

        userIdentifier = userState.getIdentifier();
        user = _userService.FindByIdentifier(userIdentifier);
        sameUser = userIdentifier == SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        authorities = GetAuthorities();

        if(!sameUser || authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("");
        }

        if(!authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN") && !user.isEnabled())
        {
            resendButton.setVisible(false);
            resendButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

        ConfigureResendButton();
        ConfigureDeleteButton();
        ConfigureUserForm();
        ConfigureGrids();
        ConfigureTextFields();
        UserReload();
        ReloadAll();

        SetContent();
    }

    // == public methods ==
    // == private methods ==

    private void ConfigureDeleteButton()
    {
        deleteButton.setVisible(!sameUser && authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        deleteButton.setEnabled(!sameUser && authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        deleteButton.addClickListener(t -> DeleteUser());
        deleteButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_ERROR);
    }

    private void DeleteUser()
    {
        _userService.DeleteUser(userIdentifier);
        UI.getCurrent().navigate("users");
    }

    private void SetContent()
    {
        HorizontalLayout userToolBar = new HorizontalLayout(userTilte, resendButton, deleteButton);

        HorizontalLayout responsibleForToolbar = new HorizontalLayout(responsibleForTitle, responsibleForField);
        VerticalLayout responsibleForView = new VerticalLayout(responsibleForToolbar, responsibleForGrid);

        HorizontalLayout createdWorksToolbar = new HorizontalLayout(createdWorksTitle, createdWorksField);
        VerticalLayout createdWorksView = new VerticalLayout(createdWorksToolbar, createdWorksGrid);

        HorizontalLayout updatedWorksToolbar = new HorizontalLayout(updatedWorksTitle, updatedWorksField);
        VerticalLayout updatedWorksView = new VerticalLayout(updatedWorksToolbar, updatedWorksGrid);

        HorizontalLayout createdVehiclesToolbar = new HorizontalLayout(createdVehiclesTitle, createdVehiclesField);
        VerticalLayout createdVehiclesView = new VerticalLayout(createdVehiclesToolbar,createdVehiclesGrid);

        HorizontalLayout updatedVehiclesToolbar = new HorizontalLayout(updatedVehiclesTitle, updatedVehiclesField);
        VerticalLayout updatedVehiclesView = new VerticalLayout(updatedVehiclesToolbar, updatedVehiclesGrid);

        VerticalLayout finalView = new VerticalLayout(userToolBar, userGrid, responsibleForView, createdWorksView, updatedWorksView,
                createdVehiclesView, updatedVehiclesView);

        finalView.setSizeFull();
        HorizontalLayout formView = new HorizontalLayout(finalView,userForm);
        formView.setFlexGrow(2,finalView);
        formView.setFlexGrow(1,userForm);
        formView.setSizeFull();
        add(
                formView
        );
    }

    private void UserReload()
    {
        userGrid.setItems(_userService.FindByIdentifier(userIdentifier));
    }
    private void responibleGridReload(String filter)
    {
        responsibleForGrid.setItems(_workService.FindAllByResponsiblePerson(userIdentifier, filter));
    }

    private void createdWorksGridReload(String filter)
    {
        createdWorksGrid.setItems(_workService.FindAllByCreatedBy(userIdentifier, filter));
    }

    private void updatedWorksGridReload(String filter)
    {
        updatedWorksGrid.setItems(_workService.FindAllByUpdatedBy(userIdentifier,filter));
    }

    private void createdVehiclesReload(String filter)
    {
        createdVehiclesGrid.setItems(_vehicleService.FindAllbyCreatedBy(userIdentifier, filter));
    }

    private void updatedVehiclesGridReload(String filter)
    {
        updatedVehiclesGrid.setItems(_vehicleService.FindAllbyUpdatedBy(userIdentifier,filter));
    }

    private void ReloadAll()
    {
        UserReload();
        responibleGridReload("");
        createdWorksGridReload("");
        updatedWorksGridReload("");
        createdVehiclesReload("");
        updatedVehiclesGridReload("");
    }

    private void ConfigureUserForm()
    {
        userForm = new UserForm(_userService);
        userForm.deleteButton.setVisible(true);
        userForm.setWidth("25em");

        userForm.AddListener(UserForm.SaveEvent.class, this::UpdateUser);
        userForm.AddListener(UserForm.DeleteEvent.class, this::DeleteUser);
        userForm.AddListener(UserForm.CloseEvent.class, t -> CloseUserForm());

        userForm.setVisible(false);
    }

    private void OpenUserForm(UserDisplay userDisplay)
    {
        if(userDisplay == null)
        {
            CloseUserForm();
            return;
        }
        userForm.SetSelectedUser(userDisplay);
        userForm.setVisible(true);
       addClassName("editing");
    }

    private void UpdateUser(UserForm.SaveEvent event)
    {
        _userService.SaveUser(event.GetUserDisplay());
        CloseUserForm();
        ReloadAll();
    }

    public void DeleteUser(UserForm.DeleteEvent event)
    {
        _userService.DeleteUser(event.GetUserDisplay().getIdentifier());
        CloseUserForm();
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("/user");
    }

    private void CloseUserForm()
    {
        userForm.SetSelectedUser(null);
        userForm.setVisible(false);
        removeClassName("editing");

        userGrid.deselectAll();
    }

    private void ConfigureResendButton()
    {
        resendButton.setVisible(!user.isEnabled());
        resendButton.setEnabled(!user.isEnabled());

        resendButton.addClickListener(t -> _emailSenderService.SendSetPasswortMail("oliver01@kabsi.at", user.getIdentifier(), user.getName()));
    }

    private void ConfigureTextFields()
    {
        responsibleForField.setPlaceholder("Search responsibilities");
        responsibleForField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        responsibleForField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        responsibleForField.addValueChangeListener(e -> responibleGridReload(responsibleForField.getValue()));

        createdWorksField.setPlaceholder("Search responsibilities");
        createdWorksField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        createdWorksField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        createdWorksField.addValueChangeListener(e -> createdWorksGridReload(createdWorksField.getValue()));

        updatedWorksField.setPlaceholder("Search responsibilities");
        updatedWorksField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        updatedWorksField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        updatedWorksField.addValueChangeListener(e -> updatedWorksGridReload(updatedWorksField.getValue()));

        createdVehiclesField.setPlaceholder("Search responsibilities");
        createdVehiclesField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        createdVehiclesField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        createdVehiclesField.addValueChangeListener(e -> createdVehiclesReload(createdVehiclesField.getValue()));

        updatedVehiclesField.setPlaceholder("Search responsibilities");
        updatedVehiclesField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
        updatedVehiclesField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
        updatedVehiclesField.addValueChangeListener(e -> updatedVehiclesGridReload(updatedVehiclesField.getValue()));
    }

    private void ConfigureGrids()
    {
        userGrid.addClassName("list-view");
        userGrid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getName).setHeader("Name").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator((u1,u2) -> u1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(u2.getName()));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getEmail).setHeader("Email").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator((u1,u2) -> u1.getEmail().compareToIgnoreCase(u2.getEmail()));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getTelephoneNumber).setHeader("Telephone Number").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator((u1,u2) -> u1.getTelephoneNumber().compareToIgnoreCase(u2.getTelephoneNumber()));

        userGrid.addColumn(RoleGridRenderer()).setHeader("Role").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getRole().ordinal()));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::isEnabled).setHeader("Enabled").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true);

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getResponsibleFor).setHeader("Responsible For").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingLong(UserDisplay::getResponsibleFor));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getCreatedVehicles).setHeader("Created Vehicles").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingLong(UserDisplay::getCreatedVehicles));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getUpdatedVehicles).setHeader("Updated Vehicles").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingLong(UserDisplay::getUpdatedVehicles));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getCreatedWorks).setHeader("Created Works").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingLong(UserDisplay::getCreatedWorks));

        userGrid.addColumn(UserDisplay::getUpdatedWorks).setHeader("Updated Vehicles").setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER).setSortable(true)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingLong(UserDisplay::getUpdatedWorks));

        userGrid.getColumns().forEach(col -> col.setAutoWidth(true));
        userGrid.setHeight("6em");

        userGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener(t -> OpenUserForm(t.getValue()));


        responsibleForGrid.addClassName("list-view");
        responsibleForGrid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);

        responsibleForGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getVehicle).setHeader("Vehicle").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((r1,r2) -> r1.getVehicle().compareToIgnoreCase(r2.getVehicle()));
        responsibleForGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getDescription).setHeader("Description").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((d1, d2) -> d1.getDescription().compareToIgnoreCase(d2.getDescription()));
        responsibleForGrid.addColumn(CreatePrioritiesRenderer()).setHeader("Priority").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getPriority().ordinal()));

        responsibleForGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener( t -> UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("vehicle/" + t.getValue().getVehicleIdentifier()));
        responsibleForGrid.setHeight("400px");


        createdWorksGrid.addClassName("list-view");
        createdWorksGrid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);

        createdWorksGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getResponsiblePerson).setHeader("Responsible Person").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((r1,r2) -> r1.getResponsiblePerson().compareToIgnoreCase(r2.getResponsiblePerson()));
        createdWorksGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getVehicle).setHeader("Vehicle").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((r1,r2) -> r1.getVehicle().compareToIgnoreCase(r2.getVehicle()));
        createdWorksGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getDescription).setHeader("Description").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((d1, d2) -> d1.getDescription().compareToIgnoreCase(d2.getDescription()));
        createdWorksGrid.addColumn(CreatePrioritiesRenderer()).setHeader("Priority").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getPriority().ordinal()));

        createdWorksGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener( t -> UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("vehicle/" + t.getValue().getVehicleIdentifier()));
        createdWorksGrid.setHeight("400px");


        updatedWorksGrid.addClassName("list-view");
        updatedWorksGrid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);

        updatedWorksGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getResponsiblePerson).setHeader("Responsible Person").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((r1,r2) -> r1.getResponsiblePerson().compareToIgnoreCase(r2.getResponsiblePerson()));
        updatedWorksGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getVehicle).setHeader("Vehicle").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((r1,r2) -> r1.getVehicle().compareToIgnoreCase(r2.getVehicle()));
        updatedWorksGrid.addColumn(WorkDisplay::getDescription).setHeader("Description").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator((d1, d2) -> d1.getDescription().compareToIgnoreCase(d2.getDescription()));
        updatedWorksGrid.addColumn(CreatePrioritiesRenderer()).setHeader("Priority").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER)
                .setComparator(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.getPriority().ordinal()));

        updatedWorksGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener( t -> UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("vehicle/" + t.getValue().getVehicleIdentifier()));
        updatedWorksGrid.setHeight("400px");


        createdVehiclesGrid.addClassName("list-view");
        createdVehiclesGrid.setSizeFull();
        createdVehiclesGrid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);

        createdVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getType).setHeader("Type").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        createdVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getNumber).setHeader("Number").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        createdVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getStatus).setHeader("Status").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        createdVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getStand).setHeader("Stand").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        createdVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getWorkCount).setHeader("Works").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);

        createdVehiclesGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener( t -> UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("vehicle/" + t.getValue().getIdentifier()));
        createdVehiclesGrid.setHeight("400px");


        updatedVehiclesGrid.addClassName("list-view");
        updatedVehiclesGrid.setSizeFull();
        updatedVehiclesGrid.addThemeVariants(GridVariant.LUMO_ROW_STRIPES);

        updatedVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getType).setHeader("Type").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        updatedVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getNumber).setHeader("Number").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        updatedVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getStatus).setHeader("Status").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        updatedVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getStand).setHeader("Stand").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);
        updatedVehiclesGrid.addColumn(VehicleDisplay::getWorkCount).setHeader("Works").setSortable(true).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.CENTER);

        updatedVehiclesGrid.asSingleSelect().addValueChangeListener( t -> UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("vehicle/" + t.getValue().getIdentifier()));
        updatedVehiclesGrid.setHeight("400px");
    }

}
```

The MainLayout:

```
/**
 * The main view is a top-level placeholder for other views.
 */
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout {

    /**
     * A simple navigation item component, based on ListItem element.
     */
    public static class MenuItemInfo extends ListItem
    {

        private final Class<? extends Component> view;

        public MenuItemInfo(String menuTitle, Component icon, Class<? extends Component> view) {
            this.view = view;
            RouterLink link = new RouterLink();
            // Use Lumo classnames for various styling
            link.addClassNames(Display.FLEX, Gap.XSMALL, Height.MEDIUM, AlignItems.CENTER, Padding.Horizontal.SMALL,
                    TextColor.BODY);
            link.setRoute(view);

            Span text = new Span(menuTitle);
            // Use Lumo classnames for various styling
            text.addClassNames(FontWeight.MEDIUM, FontSize.MEDIUM, Whitespace.NOWRAP);

            if (icon != null) {
                link.add(icon);
            }
            link.add(text);
            add(link);
        }


        public Class<?> getView() {
            return view;
        }

    }
    private final SecurityService _securityService;
    private final UserService _userService;
    public MainLayout(SecurityService securityService, UserService userService)
    {
        _securityService = securityService;
        _userService = userService;
        addToNavbar(createHeaderContent());
    }

    private Component createHeaderContent() {
        Header header = new Header();
        header.addClassNames(BoxSizing.BORDER, Display.FLEX, FlexDirection.COLUMN, Width.FULL);

        Div layout = new Div();
        layout.addClassNames(Display.FLEX, AlignItems.CENTER, Padding.Horizontal.LARGE);

        H1 appName = new H1("OegegEtdJava");
        appName.addClassNames(Margin.Vertical.MEDIUM, Margin.End.AUTO, FontSize.LARGE);
        layout.add(appName);

        Nav nav = new Nav();
        nav.addClassNames(Display.FLEX, Overflow.AUTO, Padding.Horizontal.MEDIUM, Padding.Vertical.XSMALL);

        // Wrap the links in a list; improves accessibility
        UnorderedList list = new UnorderedList();
        list.addClassNames(Display.FLEX, Gap.SMALL, ListStyleType.NONE, Margin.NONE, Padding.NONE);
        nav.add(list);

        for (MenuItemInfo menuItem : createMenuItems()) {
            list.add(menuItem);

        }
        list.add();

        header.add(layout, nav);
        return header;
    }

    private MenuItemInfo[] createMenuItems()
    {
        if(Objects.requireNonNull(GetAuthorities()).contains("ROLE_ADMIN") ||
                Objects.requireNonNull(GetAuthorities()).contains("ROLE_LEADER"))
        {
            return new MenuItemInfo[]{ //
                    new MenuItemInfo("Vehicles", LineAwesomeIcon.GLOBE_SOLID.create(), VehiclesView.class), //

                    new MenuItemInfo("Users", LineAwesomeIcon.FILE.create(), UserView.class), //

                    new MenuItemInfo(_userService.FindByIdentifier(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()).getName(),
                            LineAwesomeIcon.USER.create(),ProfileView.class),
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new MenuItemInfo[]{ //
                    new MenuItemInfo("Vehicles", LineAwesomeIcon.GLOBE_SOLID.create(), VehiclesView.class), //
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i log in to the app? I really want to help you but this only works if I know which branch to use. How to create the database how to create users etc.

Comment: Oh i am sorry i completely forgot this. Use the Branch StackoverflowHelp. For the database set up i think you only need to name it oegegetd with username root and password Passwort, they are also visible in the application.properties i think you do not need more. When the database is set up un this branch three standard users are saved automatically with their role respectively: user, leader, admin. All of these have the password Passwort.

Comment: Ok i spent hours yesterday looking at the console in the browser and fiddler it was devestating. Now i found out that the proble mwas this line 
```
if(!sameUser || authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("");
        }
```
since it set the navigation to an empty string and it did not find anything so it seems it was in some kind of between state and could not do anything else anymore. Changing it to "/" made everything work. It still confuses me a bit but it works now.

Comment: why do you even use setLocation and not navigate?

Comment: @WoistdasNiveau If you have solved the problem yourself, feel free to add an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error lies in the line

```
if(!sameUser || authorities.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation("");
        }
```

as no path for "" exists. We have to change it to "/" which exists and then everything works. Otherwise it seems the program is in a strange navigation state between the site in shows and a site that does not exist so there is no possibility to navigate further.